# Trouble INSERT INTO string value into DATETIME msSQL datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have looked all over the place and I can't find the answer.

Here is the error I am getting using ColdFusion and MsSQL

```
Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The error occurred in SQL

INSERT INTO Requests ( 
    RequestName, 
    RequestEmail, 
    RequestPhone, 
    RequestType, 
    RequestSiteSection, 
    RequestDue, 
    RequestUrgent, 
    RequestTitle, 
    RequestURL, 
    RequestMessage, 
    Attachment1, 
    Attachment2, 
    Attachment3, 
    Attachment4, 
    Attachment5, 
    RequestCreated, 
    RequestModified, 
    RequestPriority, 
    RequestAssignedTo, 
    RequestStatus 
) 
VALUES ( 
    '', 
    'Joshua >Davis', 
    'onebigcelt@gmail.com', 
    '8046789', 
    'Correction', 
    'Natural Heritage', 
    '09/11/2013', 
    'This is the Title of the REQUEST!', 
    'http://www.dcr.virginia.com', 
    'rewas', 
    '/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/neotmp47128.tmp', 
    '', 
    '', 
    '', 
    '', 
    (param 1), 
    (param 2), 
    '0', 
    'Webmaster', 
    'Pending' 
)
```

Each param is `cfqueryparam cfsqltype='CF_SQL_timestamp' value='#CreateODBCDateTime(now())#'`

**this error comes up when I try to insert using any of the following**

- cfqueryparam cfsqltype='CF_SQL_timestamp' value='#CreateODBCDateTime(now())#'
- now()
- CreateODBCDateTime(now())
- SQL getDate()
- an other variations

I have tried concatenating time and date together, cast and convert to datetime , formating the date and time  but no luck I am stuck.

I appreciate your help.

here is the query

```
INSERT INTO Requests (
    RequestName,
    RequestEmail,
    RequestPhone,
    RequestType,
    RequestSiteSection,
    RequestDue,
    RequestUrgent,
    RequestTitle,
    RequestURL,
    RequestMessage,
    Attachment1,
    Attachment2,
    Attachment3,
    Attachment4,
    Attachment5,
    RequestCreated,
    RequestModified,
    RequestPriority,
    RequestAssignedTo,
    RequestStatus
)
VALUES(
   '<cfif IsDefined('form.requestUrgent')>#form.requestUrgent#</cfif>',
   '#form.requestName#',
   '#form.requestEmail#',
   '#form.requestPhone#',
   '#form.requestType#',
   '#form.requestSection#',
   '#form.requestDueDate#',
   '#form.requestTitle#',
   '#form.requestURL#',
   '#form.requestMessage#',
   '#form.attachment1#',
   '#form.attachment2#',
   '#form.attachment3#',
   '#form.attachment4#',
   '#form.attachment5#',
   getdate(),
   getdate(),
   '0',
   'Webmaster',
   'Pending'
)
```

You can sub out the `getDate()` with any of the above options `#var#` convert cast, param, etc

Comment: what's the format of the element in the Requests table ?

Comment: You may find it easier to troubleshoot wrapping all of your variables in cfqueryparam tags to make sure that your field values don't contain characters that are also breaking your script (along with the need for sql injection prevention).... Your code may be related to an earlier date mentioned in your sql code.. also <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#now()#"> will suffice for a mssql date field. cf_sql_timestamp for a date/time field.

Comment: Your variables seem to be off in your example code. Your insert begins with the column `RequestName` but the first variable in your VALUES clause is `form.requestUrgent` and then `form.requestName` etc. And you should be using `<cfqueryparam>` tags for ALL of your variable values.

Comment: Because your initial columns and data are off (see previous comment) I think the error is actually occurring on the `RequestDue` column, which also appears to be a date column. Your example is attempting to insert `'Natural Heritage'` into that date column.

Comment: (Edit) @Miguel-F - You should post that as an answer. Onebigcelt - Also, to reiterate you really should using cfqueryparam on **all** of the parameters - not just some of them. Both to protect against sql injection and improve performance.

Comment: It appears that @Miguel-F has eyeballed the answer.  Since my eyes are not that good, my approach would have been to comment out every field and value execpt the first one.  Then I would run the query.  If successful, I would uncomment field/value pairs one by one until an error occurred.  Then I would know the cause.

Answer (score 5):

*From the comments*

The columns and values from your insert query seem to be off in your example code. Your insert begins with the column `RequestName` but the first variable in your VALUES clause is `form.requestUrgent` and then `form.requestName` etc. Because of this your query is attempting to insert `form.requestSection` ('Natural Heritage' in your example) into the date column `RequestDue`.

Excerpt from your example:

```
INSERT INTO Requests ( 
    RequestName,                /* column 1 */
    RequestEmail,               /* column 2 */
    RequestPhone,               /* column 3 */
    RequestType,                /* column 4 */
    RequestSiteSection,         /* column 5 */
    RequestDue,                 /* column 6 */
    RequestUrgent,              /* column 7 */
    RequestTitle,               /* column 8 */
....


VALUES (
   '<cfif IsDefined('form.requestUrgent')>#form.requestUrgent#</cfif>', /* value 1 */
   '#form.requestName#',        /* value 2 */
   '#form.requestEmail#',       /* value 3 */
   '#form.requestPhone#',       /* value 4 */
   '#form.requestType#',        /* value 5 */
   '#form.requestSection#',     /* value 6 */
   '#form.requestDueDate#',     /* value 7 */
   '#form.requestTitle#',       /* value 8 */
....
```

And I cannot stress enough **you should be using `<cfqueryparam>` tags for ALL of your variable values**. It helps [protect against SQL injection](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/protecting-coldfusion-server-behaviors-sql.html) and also [improves query performance](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion_performance.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1).

Comment: That was it! I knew it was going to be something simple. I will change all the params as you suggested

Comment: @Onebigcelt - great, glad I could help (and believe me, we have all done things like this). If this worked for you don't forget to accept it as the answer so that others can find it more easily. Thanks.